# How do I transfer ownership of all a user's Google Earth Engine assets to another user?

Tags: google-earth-engine

I am hoping to find a quick and easy way to transfer all of one Google Earth Engine account's assets to another - we had an employee leave and we are unable to close their Google account until we transfer ownership.

Answer (score 0):

I think the best way will be to share the asset. Once the asset is fully shared, then may be the new receiver can try saving it or exporting it again as new asset making it their new asset.

Answer (score 0):

There's no way for a regular user to transfer ownership.  You will have to share the assets with another account and then use the command line tool with another account's credentials to make a copy.